# How can I get p-value by using ecdf and bootstrapping?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, bootstrap, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

First of all, forgive my for my ignorance about this concept. I might ask a basic question but what I have read from [Exploratory Data Analysis: 2 Ways of Plotting Empirical Cumulative Distribution Functions in R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/exploratory-data-analysis-2-ways-of-plotting-empirical-cumulative-distribution-functions-in-r/) , [How to calculate cumulative distribution in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30858/how-to-calculate-cumulative-distribution-in-r)  and [Distribution empirical in R](http://Distribution%20empirical%20in%20R) did not guide me to my aim.

I have 248 genes with enrichment measure and by sorting this enrichment measures we were able to assign a enrichment score to the specific intervals to the data. On the other hand, I have my protein complex which contain these genes. By adding up enrichment scores we thought we can generate a protein complex enrichment score. For statistical validation, I would like to randomly generate 1000 protein complexes (for every unique protein complex, i will change the number of genes overtime) and compare those random score with our score.

```
 In descending order
 Top +25 --- +2
  26- 51 --- +1
  51-150 ---  0
 151-200 --- -1
 200-248 --- -2
```

For comparison, I thought, nonparametric fitting of my random scores in a distribution, then piping our protein complex score and obtaining a p value would work.

My questions: (Both of the following functions are in R)

1. For non parametric fitting, `approxfun(density(random_genarated_sums))` object will give my a distribution function. Can I calculate the probability of my protein complex with inputting it to distribution function ?
2. I asked the same question to my advisors and he suggested me to use `ecdf(x)`. But when since it is cumulative, i get both 0.01 or .998 as a value so should I 1-ecdf(x) for  p>0.5? Will this give "p-value"?

I have read about bootstrapping in both CrossValidated and R stackexchange. In those threads, bootstrapping were dont by setting up a hypothesis by;

```
 Generate 1000 random protein complexes of 6 genes
 If random sum is greater than > protein complex sum
 +1 to count
 at the end p value is count / total number of iterations (10000)
```

I am very confused with this question so any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 2, yes.

When you are doing a two-tail test using ecdf(distribution)(your score), if the p>0.5, you need to manually do 1-p to get the pvalue.

But if you need a one-tail test, like some enrichment test when you trying to test if the observed expression level is significantly higher than null hypothesis, just use 1-p is

Comment: If the test is 2-sided, should the `p` for question two be multiplied by 2, (or `1-p` if `p > 0.5`)?